# broadcast receiver on android 8.0 not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make app that launch activity from broadcast receiver when
call was incoming and it is working on below android 8.0 but it not working on above android 8.0.
here is my code.
**MyReceiver**

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

      try {
        tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
          PhoneStateListener psl = new PhoneStateListener(){
              @Override
              public void onCallStateChanged(int state,final  String num){


                  if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                      try {


                          new  Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                                  i.putExtra("num", num);

                                  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                                  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                  context.startActivity(i);
                              }
                          }, 300);

                      }catch (Exception e){

                      }
                  }
```

in manifest

```
  <receiver android:name="com.deva.caller.Receiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
</intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

Comment: it have solution or not ?